# Case Statement in CakePHP generates another array of the result

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a simple select query using Case Statement in CakePHP.

```
 $this->M->find('all', array(
                'fields'=>array(
                    'M.id',
                    '(CASE WHEN M.check> 0 THEN
                        TRUNCATE((M.col1 + M.col2),2)
                    ELSE
                        TRUNCATE(M.col2, 2)
                    END) AS TOTAL'
                )));
```

I'm trying to have this result.

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'M' => array(
            'id' => '200',
            'TOTAL' => '1073.00'
        )
    )
```

But Cake Outputs

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'M' => array(
            'id' => '200',
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'TOTAL' => '1073.00'
        )
    )
```

Does cake renders the result like this for the Case Statement or I miss out something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html
as documented.

```
$this->virtualFields['total'] = ...;
```

Then it would work as expected.

Comment: Using Virtual fields property of CakePHP, Now I can have the result I'm looking for.